# Design a query for SSRS report to switch between hour, day and month time period grouping

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have this code that works as I want.

```
    SELECT
    DATEADD(
        DAY,
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            '19000101',
            fdEnterDate
        ),
        '19000101'
    ) AS theHour,
    COUNT (*) AS theCount
FROM
    DB.dbo.[table]
WHERE
    fdEnterDate >= '11/01/2014'
AND fdEnterDate < '11/11/2014'
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(
        DAY,
        DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            '19000101',
            fdEnterDate
        ),
        '19000101'
    )
ORDER BY
    theHour
```

I want to give the user a drop down to pick between hour, day and month
The code would change the four instances of 'DAY' in the query to what ever the user selected in the drop down.

I'm not sure how to approach this.  I'd rather not create a new report for each selection.

```
theHour theCount
2014-11-03 00:00:00.000 1390
2014-11-04 00:00:00.000 2027
2014-11-05 00:00:00.000 2442
2014-11-06 00:00:00.000 1284
2014-11-07 00:00:00.000 3296
2014-11-08 00:00:00.000 842
2014-11-10 00:00:00.000 1407
```

these are the results of the 'day' query so the hour would break down the results by the hour in between the dates specified.  That I know how to do but I need to know how to integrate that into an ssrs report by allowing the user to select the hour or day or month from a dropo down.

Comment: What are the current results of the query and what are your desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything in Reporting Services is an expression, including the Sql query statement. Right-click the dataset, click `Dataset Properties` and click the expression editor beside the query box, which is the `fx` button. Now we can edit the query as a string expression.

Let's say you have a parameter called `Period` with the selectable values `HOUR`, `DAY`, and `MONTH`. We change your Sql expression to this:

```
="SELECT "
&"  DATEADD(" & Parameters!Period.Value & ", DATEDIFF(" & Parameters!Period.Value & ", '19000101', fdEnterDate), '19000101') AS theHour, "
&"  COUNT (*) AS theCount "
&"FROM DB.dbo.[table] "
&"WHERE fdEnterDate >= '11/01/2014' AND fdEnterDate < '11/11/2014' "
&"GROUP BY DATEADD(" & Parameters!Period.Value & ", DATEDIFF(" & Parameters!Period.Value & ", '19000101', fdEnterDate), '19000101') "
&"ORDER BY theHour "
```

Apart from line formatting, this is exactly the same query you had, but converted to a string expression with the word `DAY` replaced by `Parameters!Period.Value`. When the report runs it evaluates the string expression inserting the period selected by the parameter and runs the result as a Sql query. Want to add `WEEK` or `YEAR` as period selections? Add them to the parameter's available values and the query will do that as well.

Comment: That worked great, I even took that concept and applied it to the table selection as each table is a different station's data.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, I even use it to select alternate databases to run reports on previous financial year's databases.